# Cross Site Scripting: DOM Fortify

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss, fortify

Currently working on addressing DOM XSS for one of my application code where it is reporting XSS for winT (provided pseudo code below).

Code Snippet:

```
Var oMyObj = window.dialogArg;
var winT = oMyObj.title;

<span id="header">
 <script>
      document.write(winT);
 </script>
</span>
```

I have tried couple of approaches to see if that helps, but so far still trying.. thought would request here to see if any option or approaches that will help to remediate fortify XSS.

We're sending static information to print in above case as page/dialog box title and application is internal/intranet app behind firewall.. but would like to see if it can be addressed

After searching and reading articles related to XSS tried following:

1. Converted line "document.write" to ".textContent" but it didnt print the value itself

```
document.getElementsbyId("header").textContent = winT
```

2. Tried innerHTML instead of document.write and it printed but didnt rectify Fortify - Later realized the innerHTML also has XSS
3. tried htmlencoder like below -- fortify still reported it as problem.
   https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/preventing

```
function htmlEncode(str){
  return String(str).replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function(c){
     return '&#'+c.charCodeAt(0)+';';
  });
}
```

Maybe I am lacking in fully understand what is causing the XSS to happen which is further leading unable to find right solution to above problem.

If you can help with few insight or guide on right direction will be helpful. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved above problem using ESAPI

Example snippet:

```
 var reportName = "<%= ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(reportName)%>";
```